# About the error encountered when noninteractively running comand by ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

```
ssh usrname@ip 'bash -c "for i in 1 2 3; do date;sleep 1;done" '
```

works well, and here is the output of the said command:

```
Sun Jun 1 11:02:12 CST 2022
Sun Jun 1 11:02:13 CST 2022
Sun Jun 1 11:02:14 CST 2022
```

Whereas the command below encounters error:

```
ssh usrname@ip 'bash -c "for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done" '
```

Here is the error message:

```
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
bash: -c: line 1: `2'
```

What confuses is that `for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done` works well in local bash or remote bash.

Tips:You can try `ssh usrname@ip 'bash -c "for i in 1 2 3; do date;sleep 1;done" '` in your local computer which has `sshd` service by replacing the `ip` to your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get the exact same error running the command locally (i.e. without `ssh`):

```
$ bash -c "for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done"
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
bash: -c: line 1: `2'
```

The reason it happens has to do with the order in which things get expanded, and when word-splitting does (or doesn't) happen. Specifically, it's because the `$(seq 1 3)` part gets expanded *before* it's passed to `bash` as part of the command to be executed But because it's in double-quotes, it's not subject to word-splitting, so the newlines between the numbers are left intact rather than being converted to breaks between words. You can see this with by turning on tracing with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done"
++ seq 1 3
+ bash -c 'for i in 1
2
3; do date;sleep 1;done'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
bash: -c: line 1: `2'
```

...so it runs `seq 1 3` *first*. That prints "1", "2", and "3" with newlines between them, so that's how they get included in the argument to `bash -c`. bash then treats the newlines as command delimiters, and you can't have a command delimiter in the middle of the list of things for `for` to iterate over. So `bash` sees a `2` where it expected a `done`, and panics.

The reason it normally works is because you usually put `$(seq 1 3)` in a context where it's not double-quoted, so the newlines just turn into word breaks. Compare:

```
$ echo $(seq 1 3)    # No double-quotes, newlines convert to word breaks
1 2 3
$ echo "$(seq 1 3)"  # With double-quotes, newlines are retained
1
2
3
```

You can fix this by escaping the `$` to delay interpretation of the `$( )` substitution until it's passed to `bash -c` (which is after the double-quotes have been applied and removed):

```
$ bash -c "for i in \$(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done"
Sat Jun 11 23:55:54 PDT 2022
Sat Jun 11 23:55:55 PDT 2022
Sat Jun 11 23:55:56 PDT 2022
```

(And that should work over `ssh` as well, provided the whole thing is in single-quotes so the local shell doesn't mess with it.)

Comment: Or `for (( i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )); do...`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Good point; since it's being explicitly run under bash, you should be able to count on the `for (( ))` syntax being available (unlike dash and some other shells that're missing this feature). And since it doesn't use `$`, you don't have to worry about premature expansion.

Comment: Or simply `for i in {1..3}`

Comment: @GordonDavisson It's strange that if I put `for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done` into a script file named `t.sh`,  and `bash -c ./t.sh` works well. What's the difference between running `bash -c ./t.sh`  and  `bash -c "for i in $(seq 1 3); do date;sleep 1;done"`?

Comment: @John It's all about the context where the `$(seq 1 3)` gets expanded. If it's in a script, it doesn't get expanded until the script runs, and it's not in double-quotes there, so it's subject to word-splitting and the newlines get converted into word breaks. It's very similar to how delaying expansion by escaping the `$` works.